# Allow "another" user to make personal backups on my server through sshd with no shell access (public key login)

Tags: shell, ssh, key-authentication, file-server

I have set up a Ubuntu server at my home just to learn "stuff". I overdid a bit and have some spare room on my SSD. I am prepared to give a friend some of that space to make backups on my computer. He will give the same opportunity to me. Profit!!

Here are the requirements/setup of my system:

- users can only login via sshd using keypairs. This is how i configured ssh on my system. Password access is not allowed.
- the additional user should not have shell access or whatever means to execute commands on my server
- i want to give sshd write and read access to a folder that is located in /mnt/copro only. He will be using duplicati over sshd to make his backups.

In general the folder should be accessible as a (dumb) file server but over ssh and access is only allowed using keypairs.

I did do some research, but i did not find an overall satisfying answer or i have not been able to correctly combine the answers i found in a working solution:

My questions therefore are:

- how do i create a user without shell access
- how do i allow such user read/write access to a folder of my choice
- where do i store the private key for that specific user

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you're using OpenSSH as your SSH server, I believe that's the default on Ubuntu.

[Duplicati's documentation](https://duplicati.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-introduction/#supported-backends) makes clear that you actually want just SFTP access; that makes this much easier.

1. You set up a `Match User` or `Match Group` section in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to match the user with several options, most critically `ForceCommand`, probably `ForceCommand internal-sftp` (there is an external sftp server that you might use instead in some cases, and this can actually be any command — it can also be used for things like only `git` access, for example.) You'll also want to prevent the various forwardings, most likely. Unfortunately you have to keep an eye out for SSH upgrades adding more; last I checked you want (note some of these default to no):

```
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    AllowStreamLocalForwarding no
    PermitTTY no
    PermitTunnel no
    PermitUserEnvironment no
    PermitUserRC no
    X11Forwarding no
```

2. First, you start with filesystem permissions. This should protect your personal files; your `$HOME` ought not be readable by the other user!

   However, there are a bunch of places which are globally readable (but you may not really care if the user can read `/bin/sh`; surely he/she could just download it from your distro). There are also a few globally-writable directories like `/tmp`. You can protect both of these using ChrootDirectory, but note that the chroot directory needs to be root-owned and not writable by the user (else is a huge security issue, and sshd won't permit it). So if you have `ChrootDirectory /mnt/copro`, then you need to have that be `0755 root:root`, and have a `/mnt/copro/data` (or similar) inside, owned by the user. For security reasons, its name should definitely not be `etc` or any of the other common top-level directories (`bin`, `usr`, `lib`, etc.).
3. The easiest is probably to just put the authorized keys file in the normal place in the user's home directory (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, just like any other user). That home directory should probably be outside of `/mnt/copro`, as it's best not to let a restricted user write to his own `$HOME` if possible. You can, if needed, set an alternative location with the `AuthorizedKeysFile` inside the `Match` block.

PS: Duplicati supports other backends. So if you're more familiar with setting up e.g., Apache, maybe you want to suggest WebDAV instead. Or maybe you have a serious amount of storage and you can offer an S3-compatible interface, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I got it working. But i did it quite different. Since i did not get it to work in the first place (too many variables), i started in the opposite direction. First i created a "regular" user (useradd), i removed the pwd login (passwd -l user). Then I copied the public key to ~/.ssh. I changed config in sshd_conf to only allow sftp access to a certain folder. And lastly i took away shell login. I was able to track easily when and where it went wrong and have been able to correct step by step. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To create user account with no shell access,

```
sudo adduser --shell /bin/false mysftpfriend
```

You should create a directory and directory structure for the mysftpfriend and make it accessible for them.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/mysftpfriends/storage
```

To give access,

```
sudo chown mysftpfriend:mysftpfriend /var/mysftpfriends/storage
```

Simply set the root to have full access (owner and group owner) to mysftpfriends directory.

```
sudo chown root:root /var/mysftpfriends
sudo chmod 0766 /var/mysftpfriends
```

Group members can read/write but cannot execute.

Now,to configure the SSH meant for SFTP alone, open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in a text editor (nano or vim),

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

add following lines to the end of the file,

```
Match User mysftpfriend
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /var/mysftpfriends
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

save the file, exit the editor and restart ssh.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

that's all, now try to ssh to your console and test for file read/write and make sure the sftpfriend user cant execute.

```
sftp mysftpfriend@myserver
```

All done!

Comment: I tried this solution. `code`test

Comment: I tried this solution. but i changed (commented) "PasswordAuthentication", since login through ssh is only allowed with keypairs. I created a working keypair in the home directory of user mysftpfriend (i used "copro"). now i get the following message in /var/log/auth.log :  `Sep 11 21:52:17 localhost sshd[5645]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/mnt/externalbackups" `. Duplicati gives me the following message:  `Failed to connect: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host `

Comment: "Failed to connect: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" - this occurs when you try to connect just ftp rather than sftp.  Do you use ftp package like "proftpd" or something? If so, add the user name in the overwrites.